# Grails/SpringSecurity: Login and logout

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am new in Grails and Spring Security and my goal is to build sample site with sample register/login/logout functionality. The registration is ready and now I need to login and logout.

I already executed the s2-quickstart command and I have User, Role and UserRole classes. I can perform register and I see that all is fine in the DB.

Part of my User domain class:

```
static constraints = {
        userFullname blank: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
        password blank: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
        userEmail email: true, unique: true, blank: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
    }
```

I have LoginController with sample form for logging. The form includes fields for email and password. Grails version 2.4.3

Questions:

1. How to implement the login logic?
2. How to implement the logout logic?

Comment: You should really use something like Spring Security Core plugin. It does this for you and is probably more secure than what you'd (or me, or most other people) end up writing.

Comment: Hi Zoran119, thank you for your response. I am using SSCore plugin in Grails application, but I can't understand how to authorise the user and how to logout the user? Can you suggest some guide, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring security, just run s2-quickstart script in cmd

```
grails s2-quickstart User Role
```

And it'll be generate User, Role and Login/Logout controllers with custom view.

Comment: Hi, Koloritnij and thank you for your response. By the newest version controllers are not generated. I already executed the s2-quickstart command and I have User, Role and UserRole classes. I can perform register and I see that all is fine in the DB. But I do not know how to authorise and logout user. Any guides in this line, please?

Comment: Hi, bel for first I'll try to find a copy of login/logout controller in the web and ctrl+c/ctrl+v :) Or you can set a previously version of spring security and run script, after change to the last.  It isn't a good solution, but must help you